# validation_data in tf.keras.model.fit doesn't seem to work with generator

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I tried to train with model.fit_generator in Colab like this:

```
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=80, epochs=10,
                          validation_data = validation_generator,validation_steps=10,
                          verbose=1)
```

It works as expected but there is a warning saying fit_generator is deprecated so I tried to use model.fit:

```
history = model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=80, epochs=10,
                validataion_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=10,
                verbose=1)
```

The training works but there is no validation after each epoch.  history.history[val_loss] is also not found.  I wonder why there is no validation. Is it because the validation_data is from a generator?

Answer (score 1):

No, generator as validation data feeder should work.

I run into the similar problem. I was substituting `model.fix_generator()` with `model.fit()`. Except I also changed the number of `batch_size` in generator, precisely validation data generator, while I did not changed the `validation_steps`. So at the first epoch it informed me about not enough input data, and continued evaluating another epochs without any warnings. As the problem was only with validation data set, it just stopped evaluating the validation. As soon as I got the numbers right (`batch_size * validation_steps <= validation_set_size`), it started to evaluate also the validation metrics.

Answer (score -1):

The model.fit_generator is going to be deleted from TensorFlow, so, please add the generator code including .flowfromdirectory code maybe there is an error in it, then we may help you.

Comment: Here is how I do the flowfromdirectory for the validation generator:
 validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    VALIDATION_DIR,
    target_size=(150,150),
    class_mode='categorical'
)


The output is:
Found 372 images belonging to 3 classes.